# Launch R shiny interface

Tags: c#, r, vbscript, shiny

I created my run.vbs script following [this tutorial](http://blog.skyscorer.com/2014/03/17/packaging-your-shiny-app-as-windows).

When I launch run.vbs manually, GoogleChromePortable opens and I can access to my application, but when I call it from my C# application (`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(mypath + "run.vbs"));`
nothing happens. The "random" file is not created and I don't have error. I replaced the relative path in run.vbs by absolute path to avoid the error "The system could not find the file specified", but I'm still stucked in my WinForms app.

I tried to create .bat and .cmd, they all work fine manually but not by code execution. I tried the |process.WaitForExit()| :

```
var process = Process.Start(mypath + "run.bat");
process.WaitForExit();
```

no GoogleChromePortable window...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is my solution...

In the tutorial, the runShinyApp.R refers to a relative path (`./Shiny`) which is not initialized when I call the run.vbs from my application.

So, I replaced run.vbs by run.bat, and I call runShinyApp.R with this bat, containing :

```
CD /d "%~dp0"
%~dp0R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin\Rscript.exe --vanilla %~dp0runShinyApp.R
```